# Wave animations in end of list (android)

Tags: android, animation, scroll, android-recyclerview

I try to make something like that: [image: wave animation] In this example wave on top, I try to made in "footer". Yes, I know - that wave is default, but it not work for me.

In program I use Recycle view, and if scroll to end of list very fast I can see that wave, but if I scroll slow i not see that wave.

Example - like gmail android.
In that example google inc. in end of list add empty place and when you drag to top - you can see that wave.

Any idea?

Comment: i think is by default like that